# Banshee crashes on Arch Linux x86_64 after a few seconds

Tags: arch-linux

Whenever I run Banshee, a few seconds after starting it crashes.
I am using Arch Linux and made sure all packages on the computer were up to date.

Running banshee > output 2> output yields the following:

```
banshee: PeakFinder.cpp:150: int soundtouch::PeakFinder::findCrossingLevel(const float*, float, int, int) const: Assertion `peaklevel >= level' failed.

Native stacktrace:

    banshee() [0x4969f9]
    /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0xf0e0) [0x7f3c8bf9a0e0]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x39) [0x7f3c8bc131c9]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(abort+0x148) [0x7f3c8bc145c8]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x2e356) [0x7f3c8bc0c356]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(+0x2e402) [0x7f3c8bc0c402]
    /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0(+0xaf61) [0x7f3c4f7d4f61]
    /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0(_ZNK10soundtouch10PeakFinder13getPeakCenterEPKfi+0x8a) [0x7f3c4f7d506a]
    /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0(_ZN10soundtouch10PeakFinder10detectPeakEPKfii+0x5f) [0x7f3c4f7d513f]
    /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0(_ZN10soundtouch9BPMDetect6getBpmEv+0x3f) [0x7f3c4f7d4d5f]
    /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstsoundtouch.so(+0x5087) [0x7f3c4f9df087]
    /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0(+0x306cc) [0x7f3c749a76cc]
    /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0(+0x310e4) [0x7f3c749a80e4]
    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0(gst_pad_push+0x29a) [0x7f3c740b724a]
    /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0(+0x3117f) [0x7f3c749a817f]
    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0(gst_pad_push+0x29a) [0x7f3c740b724a]
    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0(gst_pad_push+0x29a) [0x7f3c740b724a]
    /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0(+0x11f0c) [0x7f3c5ad63f0c]
    /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0(+0x12073) [0x7f3c5ad64073]
    /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0(gst_audio_decoder_finish_frame+0x4ae) [0x7f3c5ad68a4e]
    /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstfaad.so(+0x298e) [0x7f3c4d91898e]
    /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0(+0x1410a) [0x7f3c5ad6610a]
    /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0(+0x144a0) [0x7f3c5ad664a0]
    /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0(+0x1525b) [0x7f3c5ad6725b]
    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0(gst_pad_push+0x29a) [0x7f3c740b724a]
    /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0(gst_base_parse_push_frame+0x99e) [0x7f3c7498ab8e]
    /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0(+0x15082) [0x7f3c7498c082]
    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0(gst_pad_push+0x29a) [0x7f3c740b724a]
    /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcoreelements.so(+0x1e761) [0x7f3c5b3d2761]
    /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0(+0x86194) [0x7f3c740de194]
    /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x6cbc6) [0x7f3c87738bc6]
    /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0(+0x6c205) [0x7f3c87738205]
    /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0(+0x7dd2) [0x7f3c8bf92dd2]
    /usr/lib/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f3c8bcc3ced]

Debug info from gdb:

warning: File "/usr/bin/mono-gdb.py" auto-loading has been declined by your `auto-load safe-path' set to "$debugdir:$datadir/auto-load".
To enable execution of this file add
    add-auto-load-safe-path /usr/bin/mono-gdb.py
line to your configuration file "/home/joshua/.gdbinit".
To completely disable this security protection add
    set auto-load safe-path /
line to your configuration file "/home/joshua/.gdbinit".
For more information about this security protection see the
"Auto-loading safe path" section in the GDB manual.  E.g., run from the shell:
    info "(gdb)Auto-loading safe path"
Could not load shared library symbols for linux-vdso.so.1.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff321fe000
[New LWP 5814]
[New LWP 5813]
[New LWP 5812]
[New LWP 5811]
[New LWP 5810]
[New LWP 5809]
[New LWP 5807]
[New LWP 5806]
[New LWP 5802]
[New LWP 5801]
[New LWP 5800]
[New LWP 5799]
[New LWP 5798]
[New LWP 5797]
[New LWP 5796]
[New LWP 5795]
[New LWP 5794]
[New LWP 5793]
[New LWP 5792]
[New LWP 5791]
[New LWP 5790]
[New LWP 5789]
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/usr/lib/libthread_db.so.1".
0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
  Id   Target Id         Frame 
  23   Thread 0x7f3c8bbdd700 (LWP 5789) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  22   Thread 0x7f3c8b3dc700 (LWP 5790) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  21   Thread 0x7f3c8abdb700 (LWP 5791) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  20   Thread 0x7f3c8a3da700 (LWP 5792) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  19   Thread 0x7f3c89bd9700 (LWP 5793) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  18   Thread 0x7f3c893d8700 (LWP 5794) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  17   Thread 0x7f3c88bd7700 (LWP 5795) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  16   Thread 0x7f3c87f0f700 (LWP 5796) "mono" 0x00007f3c8bf98860 in sem_wait () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  15   Thread 0x7f3c75344700 (LWP 5797) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  14   Thread 0x7f3c6e2c4700 (LWP 5798) "gdbus" 0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
  13   Thread 0x7f3c6cf50700 (LWP 5799) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf9999d in nanosleep () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  12   Thread 0x7f3c6cf0f700 (LWP 5800) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  11   Thread 0x7f3c5bfff700 (LWP 5801) "threaded-ml" 0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
  10   Thread 0x7f3c5ad51700 (LWP 5802) "threaded-ml" 0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
  9    Thread 0x7f3c59b0f700 (LWP 5806) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  8    Thread 0x7f3c587f6700 (LWP 5807) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  7    Thread 0x7f3c583e3700 (LWP 5809) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf992ed in read () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  6    Thread 0x7f3c5990e700 (LWP 5810) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  5    Thread 0x7f3c4fffe700 (LWP 5811) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  4    Thread 0x7f3c4ef38700 (LWP 5812) "qtdemux0:sink" 0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  3    Thread 0x7f3c4e737700 (LWP 5813) "multiqueue0:src" 0x00007f3c8bf992ed in read () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
  2    Thread 0x7f3c4d6d2700 (LWP 5814) "pool" 0x00007f3c8bf96c61 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
* 1    Thread 0x7f3c8cacd740 (LWP 5787) "banshee" 0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 23 (Thread 0x7f3c8bbdd700 (LWP 5789)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005e6393 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005de645 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005e4ad7 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 22 (Thread 0x7f3c8b3dc700 (LWP 5790)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005e6393 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005de645 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005e4ad7 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 21 (Thread 0x7f3c8abdb700 (LWP 5791)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005e6393 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005de645 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005e4ad7 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 20 (Thread 0x7f3c8a3da700 (LWP 5792)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005e6393 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005de645 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005e4ad7 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 19 (Thread 0x7f3c89bd9700 (LWP 5793)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005e6393 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005de645 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005e4ad7 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 18 (Thread 0x7f3c893d8700 (LWP 5794)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005e6393 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005de645 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005e4ad7 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 17 (Thread 0x7f3c88bd7700 (LWP 5795)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005e6393 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005de645 in ?? ()
#3  0x00000000005e4ad7 in ?? ()
#4  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 16 (Thread 0x7f3c87f0f700 (LWP 5796)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf98860 in sem_wait () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005cbfb8 in mono_sem_wait ()
#2  0x000000000051598b in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000594736 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000005c134a in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000005e6194 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 15 (Thread 0x7f3c75344700 (LWP 5797)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005ab83b in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005be49d in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000059403b in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000040cc9918 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3c70000c20 in ?? ()
#6  0x0000000040cc950a in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f3c75343ae7 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f3c84021e38 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f3c70000cb0 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f3c75343b00 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f3c75343a70 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 14 (Thread 0x7f3c6e2c4700 (LWP 5798)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3c877141f4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f3c8771465a in g_main_loop_run () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f3c865e1166 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgio-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f3c87738205 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 13 (Thread 0x7f3c6cf50700 (LWP 5799)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf9999d in nanosleep () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005c0745 in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005958bb in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000594736 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000005c134a in ?? ()
#5  0x00000000005e6194 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#7  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 12 (Thread 0x7f3c6cf0f700 (LWP 5800)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005ab83b in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005beed9 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000059413d in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000040e86ae0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3c54000c20 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f3c6cf0ed98 in ?? ()
#7  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f3c6cf0eda8 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f3c54000d10 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f3c6cf0ea30 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f3c6cf0e990 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f3c6cf0ed98 in ?? ()
#13 0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#14 0x00007f3c6cf0eda8 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f3c74e65180 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000040e86798 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 11 (Thread 0x7f3c5bfff700 (LWP 5801)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3c6c49233f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#2  0x00007f3c6c48386c in pa_mainloop_poll () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#3  0x00007f3c6c483ec9 in pa_mainloop_iterate () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#4  0x00007f3c6c483f80 in pa_mainloop_run () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c6c4922ef in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#6  0x00007f3c60f5a113 in ?? () from /usr/lib/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-3.0.so
#7  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 10 (Thread 0x7f3c5ad51700 (LWP 5802)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3c6c49233f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#2  0x00007f3c6c48386c in pa_mainloop_poll () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#3  0x00007f3c6c483ec9 in pa_mainloop_iterate () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#4  0x00007f3c6c483f80 in pa_mainloop_run () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c6c4922ef in ?? () from /usr/lib/libpulse.so.0
#6  0x00007f3c60f5a113 in ?? () from /usr/lib/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-3.0.so
#7  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#8  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 9 (Thread 0x7f3c59b0f700 (LWP 5806)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005ab83b in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005beed9 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000059413d in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000040e86ae0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3c3404b3e0 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f3c58400210 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f3c54000d10 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f3c59b0ea30 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f3c54000d10 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f3c59b0ea30 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f3c59b0e990 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f3c59b0ed98 in ?? ()
#13 0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#14 0x00007f3c59b0eda8 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f3c58400210 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000040e86798 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 8 (Thread 0x7f3c587f6700 (LWP 5807)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005ab83b in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005beed9 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000059413d in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000040e86ae0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3c2c00f760 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f3c58417600 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f3c54000d10 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f3c587f5a30 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f3c54000d10 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f3c587f5a30 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f3c587f5990 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f3c587f5d98 in ?? ()
#13 0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#14 0x00007f3c587f5da8 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f3c58417600 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000040e86798 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7f3c583e3700 (LWP 5809)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf992ed in read () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000004144e287 in ?? ()
#2  0x00007f3c3000b0c0 in ?? ()
#3  0x0000000000561b84 in ?? ()
#4  0x00000000407d138a in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7f3c5990e700 (LWP 5810)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005ab83b in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005beed9 in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000059413d in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000040e86ae0 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3c38002a40 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f3c58451300 in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f3c54000d10 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f3c5990da30 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f3c54000d10 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f3c5990da30 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f3c5990d990 in ?? ()
#12 0x00007f3c5990dd98 in ?? ()
#13 0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#14 0x00007f3c5990dda8 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007f3c58451300 in ?? ()
#16 0x0000000040e86798 in ?? ()
#17 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7f3c4fffe700 (LWP 5811)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00000000005ab83b in ?? ()
#2  0x00000000005be49d in ?? ()
#3  0x000000000059403b in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000040cc9918 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007f3c24000c20 in ?? ()
#6  0x00000000407d298c in ?? ()
#7  0x00007f3c4fffd987 in ?? ()
#8  0x00007f3c5846d5f0 in ?? ()
#9  0x00007f3c70000cb0 in ?? ()
#10 0x00007f3c4fffd9a0 in ?? ()
#11 0x00007f3c4fffd910 in ?? ()
#12 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 4 (Thread 0x7f3c4ef38700 (LWP 5812)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf968b4 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f3c87753527 in g_cond_wait () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f3c749b60d8 in gst_data_queue_push () from /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
#3  0x00007f3c5b3d1a04 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcoreelements.so
#4  0x00007f3c740b724a in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c4f36f6b3 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstisomp4.so
#6  0x00007f3c4f38075c in ?? () from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstisomp4.so
#7  0x00007f3c740de194 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#8  0x00007f3c87738bc6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#9  0x00007f3c87738205 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#10 0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#11 0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7f3c4e737700 (LWP 5813)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf992ed in read () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000000000496b8b in ?? ()
#2  <signal handler called>
#3  0x00007f3c8bc131c9 in raise () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#4  0x00007f3c8bc145c8 in abort () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#5  0x00007f3c8bc0c356 in __assert_fail_base () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#6  0x00007f3c8bc0c402 in __assert_fail () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#7  0x00007f3c4f7d4f61 in soundtouch::PeakFinder::findCrossingLevel(float const*, float, int, int) const () from /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0
#8  0x00007f3c4f7d506a in soundtouch::PeakFinder::getPeakCenter(float const*, int) const () from /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0
#9  0x00007f3c4f7d513f in soundtouch::PeakFinder::detectPeak(float const*, int, int) () from /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0
#10 0x00007f3c4f7d4d5f in soundtouch::BPMDetect::getBpm() () from /usr/lib/libSoundTouch.so.0
#11 0x00007f3c4f9df087 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstsoundtouch.so
#12 0x00007f3c749a76cc in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
#13 0x00007f3c749a80e4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
#14 0x00007f3c740b724a in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#15 0x00007f3c749a817f in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
#16 0x00007f3c740b724a in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#17 0x00007f3c740b724a in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#18 0x00007f3c5ad63f0c in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0
#19 0x00007f3c5ad64073 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0
#20 0x00007f3c5ad68a4e in gst_audio_decoder_finish_frame () from /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0
#21 0x00007f3c4d91898e in ?? () from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstfaad.so
#22 0x00007f3c5ad6610a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0
#23 0x00007f3c5ad664a0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0
#24 0x00007f3c5ad6725b in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstaudio-0.10.so.0
#25 0x00007f3c740b724a in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#26 0x00007f3c7498ab8e in gst_base_parse_push_frame () from /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
#27 0x00007f3c7498c082 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstbase-0.10.so.0
#28 0x00007f3c740b724a in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#29 0x00007f3c5b3d2761 in ?? () from /usr/lib/gstreamer-0.10/libgstcoreelements.so
#30 0x00007f3c740de194 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0
#31 0x00007f3c87738bc6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#32 0x00007f3c87738205 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#33 0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#34 0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7f3c4d6d2700 (LWP 5814)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bf96c61 in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f3c87753615 in g_cond_wait_until () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f3c876eaa31 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f3c87738b98 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00007f3c87738205 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#5  0x00007f3c8bf92dd2 in start_thread () from /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007f3c8bcc3ced in clone () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f3c8cacd740 (LWP 5787)):
#0  0x00007f3c8bcbb09d in poll () from /usr/lib/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f3c877141f4 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0x00007f3c8771465a in g_main_loop_run () from /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0x00007f3c7735b8f7 in gtk_main () from /usr/lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
#4  0x00000000403de995 in ?? ()
#5  0x00007fff321278b0 in ?? ()
#6  0x00007f3c879f3938 in ?? ()
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

=================================================================
Got a SIGABRT while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the upstream bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=722551), it's not a Banshee bug but a LibSoundtouch bug, which is fixed in version 1.7.1-5. Please upgrade LibSoundtouch.